# How to use ShareOpenGraphContent on Android when Facebook is not Installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `ShareOpenGraphContent` to share image through Facebook OpenGraph in my Android app, it only works when Facebook is installed.

```
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .setCaption("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
                    G.app.getPackageName())
            .build();

    // Create an object
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "my app:type")
            .putString("og:title", "my app title")
            .putString("og:url", "https://market.android.com/details?id=" + G.app.getPackageName())
            .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("my app:object")
            .putObject("my object", object)
            .build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("type")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    final ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookShare);
    shareButton.setShareContent(content);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do some thing
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    });
```

`G.app` is [life cycle](https://github.com/Ilya-Gazman/android_life_cycle) api.

I understand that I will need publish action permission and facebook approval, for this open graph to work without facebook app been installed. But how do I do this? I want to show the user the same dialog that that they see when Facebook app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The normal fallback if the FB app is not installed is a web dialog, but the web dialogs don't support bitmaps (only urls for images), which is likely why it's not coming up for you.

You need to either switch your image to be a web url, or use the ShareApi class along with publish_actions permissions (but in that case, there won't be a dialog for your users).

Comment: You describe well the problem, now need to find a solution. How to show a dialog when facebook app is not installed.

Comment: P.S There is nothing normal in web dialog ;)